# Unable to install Ansible in ECS optimized AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ami, amazon-ecs

shell script I ran on ECS AMI

sudo yum -y install git

git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive

cd ./ansible

git submodule update --init --recursive

sudo yum -y install python

sudo yum update

sudo make install

---

Above installation works with normal AMI, with ECS optimized AMI , I get error with make install

RuntimeError: autoconf error
make: *** [install] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Create your own AMI. Install what you need. Add docker and the ecs agent so it can participate in the ecs cluster. We happen to use packer to create our amis.

Comment: Did you try to add ansible repo ?